# Set scroll speed of tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, uitableview

Using `[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:...]` to scroll to a certain table view scrolls the view too quickly to be seen as a scrolling motion, even with passing `animated:YES`. Setting `tableView.decelerationRate` doesn't seem to change the speed at which it scrolls.

Is there a way to slow down the scrolling without writing a custom animation? If so, is there a way to make sure that the scrolling has finished before calling another action? I want to call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` after it scrolls, but not until it has finished scrolling.